# Power source after load

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, components, schematics

Recently I bought a automation module for my home, and frankly it is not clear how it works.
It is a illumination module, where the installation needs just substitute the switch by the module. See the picture below:

[image]

This module has on/off and dimmer. I opened it, and inside has a pic16f690 and looks like the supply is provided from a transformerless capacitive power supply.

I tryed out this circuit, but the lamp gets flashing (about 2 in 2 seconds).

[image]

Is there some specific component, or schematic for doing that like the module?

Comment: please clarify what you tried and what happened.

Comment: VTC - Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Where's the link to the datasheet for the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is as soon as the TRIAC conducts, it shorts out the input to the power supply. As soon as the caps in the PS discharge sufficiently, the TRIAC loses power and stops conducting, allowing the PS to start up again. As soon as it starts providing power to the TRIAC again, the cycle restarts.

Modules like the one you started with are designed to always dim the light a little by starting TRIAC conduction a little after zero-crossing. This way, the PS always gets at least a little power. The PS is designed to be able to work from full line voltage (if the light is off) or from limited voltage (if the light is on but slightly dimmed).

Rather than try to create this circuit for yourself, you'd be better off using a neutral wire to provide constant power to the circuitry.

Comment: this technique has a name? I will research about it.